# How do I get the value of a Future <List <List <DocumentSnapshot >>>?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have in the cloud firestore two collections where I stored the data of certain types of products. Each of these products have three variables that are used as counters in different tasks count, count2, and count3.
What I wanted to do is go through an array with the name of these collections and compare in each collection which product has the maximum counter.

```
Future<List<List<DocumentSnapshot>>> getPopularList() async {
   List<List<DocumentSnapshot>> res = new List<List<DocumentSnapshot>>();
   var array = ['Frutas&Vegetales', 'Pan&Pasteles'];

   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await 
 Firestore.instance.collection(array[i]).getDocuments();
    var lista = querySnapshot.documents;
    int max = 0;
    int max2 = 0;
    int max3 = 0;
    DocumentSnapshot items;
    DocumentSnapshot items2;
    DocumentSnapshot items3;
    List<DocumentSnapshot> listdocs = new List<DocumentSnapshot>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
      if(lista[i]['count'] > max){
        max = lista[i]['count'];
        items = lista[i];
      }
      if(lista[i]['count2'] > max2){
        max2 = lista[i]['count2'];
        items2 = lista[i];
      } 
      if(lista[i]['count3'] > max3){
        max3 = lista[i]['count3'];
        items3 = lista[i];
      }
    }
    listdocs.add(items);
    listdocs.add(items2);
    listdocs.add(items3);
    res.add(listdocs);
  }
  return res;
}
```

I need to get the value from the list instead of an instance of Future.

Comment: If I use Future<List<List<DocumentSnapshot>>> lista_populares = getPopularList();  I have a instance of Future.

Comment: I need to iterate on that Future list to get the DocumentSnapshot of this collection. I do not know if there is another way to perform this search.

Comment: I have List<DocumentSnapshot> in the variable lista, that is a List<Future>

Comment: No, but I don't need use methods of Future class in this example

Comment: I share my code in my repository. I am using the MVP pattern, for this reason I have shared the three files. github.com/CarlesInf/application/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

use `await`

```
List<List<DocumentSnapshot>> lista_populares = await getPopularList();
```

Comment: I can't do it because if I stay inside a other method that returns a widget.                                   Widget _buildListView(List<DocumentSnapshot> lista) async {
    
   

    Future<List<List<DocumentSnapshot>>> lista_populares =  await _presenter.getPopularList();
    print(lista_populares);

    
    return ListView.builder(...)}

Comment: And if use async with await, I return a Future Widget

Comment: could you please please share your code as a gist file

Comment: Yes, I share my code in my repository. I am using the MVP pattern, for this reason I have shared the three files. https://github.com/CarlesInf/application/tree/master

Comment: You may please try to use streambuilder/futurebuilder in the _buildListView() method to create UI after fetching the data from firestore

ie: to call this method _presenter.getPopularList(list_snapshot)

Comment: Can more than one StreamBuilder / FutureBuilder be used on the same page? Because I had problems in other projects.

Comment: Sorry. I have not tried any. You have to wait to get the data from the server before rendering the UI